# Xcode - Setting Text of Label returns (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, label, xib

I just want to change the text of a Label. There for I have a ViewController to a Xib-Interface where the label is created in and linked to the ViewController. I just create an instance of this view controller an want to change the text of the label:

```
NewFormScoreViewController * newPoints=[[NewFormScoreViewController alloc] init];
[newPoints.TheNewScoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",newScore]];
[newPoints.view setFrame:CGRectMake(500, 500, newPoints.view.frame.size.width,  newPoints.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:newPoints.view];
```

The view is visible but there is just the placeholder displayed, and not the new String. [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",newScore] returns the needed String, but it seems like the transfer doesn't work. But why? What's wrong?

Comment: Do you want to change the value of yourLabel (resided in Second View Controller) from First View Controller ?

Comment: I want to change the label from the view, where the viewcontrollersview is loaded as subview, I tried also to add a method inside the NewFormScoreViewController which changes the label, the data was transfered correctly, but if I used [label setText:STRING] and after there were a NSLog that returns the Label text it was also (null)

Answer (score 1):

In a `stringWithFormat:` method, if your variable is an `int`, use `%d`, if it is a float, `%f`, `%@` for `NSString` or other types.

Comment: BTW : does the init method of your class `NewFormScoreViewController` set a width and height? if not, when you set a new frame on the third line, you will obtain a frame (500 500 , 0 x 0)

Comment: the view Controller is linked to a xib with the label and a backgroundimage and the subview added shows the bahckground image and the label with the placeholdertext

Answer (score 0):

use This one...

```
[newPoints.TheNewScoreLabel setText:newScore];
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about **"from where"** you want to change the Value of your `UILabel`. If you simply want to change the value of `UILabel` from the same View Controller then you can do it like this way:

```
yourLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newScore];
```

But if you want to change the value from other `UIViewController` then there are two possibilities. You can pass the Data Forward as well as Backward.

In that case, you should refer : [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/1603072).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[newPoints.TheNewScoreLabel setText:newScore];
```

OR

```
[newPoints.TheNewScoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newScore]];
```

instead of

```
[newPoints.TheNewScoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",newScore]];
```

because

%d scans an integer as a signed decimal number, but **%i** allows defaults to decimal but also allows hexadecimal (if preceded by "0x") and octal if preceded by "0".

Comment: but the String [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",newScore] or what ever works fine

Comment: @BJS do you get "newScore" value what you need ? If yes then try [self.view addSubview:newPoints] only..tell me that works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok.

But the class is a black box.
Is this storyboard, nib file or manual implementation?

Is the pointer for the label object actally stored in the ivar?